# How to call wordpress function directly from url?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have added custom payment method to woocommerce and its working fine . I just have one problem that it calls a callback url for saving transaction information to db. I have created new function for this in my plugin file but i cant excess it directly .
This is how i have done it:

//`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_payment_callback_action', 'payment_callback_action');`

//function
`function payment_callback_action() {
    echo "Its Working!";
}`

I am trying to access it by :
`url:"<?=site_url( '/' );?>wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=payment_callback_action`

It seemd that it because of i dnt have privillage to use it directly but how can i do this ?.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# for users not logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_payment_callback_action', 'dixipay_callback_action');

# for users logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_payment_callback_action', 'dixipay_callback_action');

# Your callback
function dixipay_callback_action() { 
  echo "Its Working!"; 
}
```

read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks that link helped . It was a spell mistake on my side . add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_payment_callback_action', 'payment_callback_action');